# How to echo php code inside html which is inside php code in this situation?

Tags: php

I am trying to echo buddypress member link. I cannot echo code because it is within html code. See code below, php code within a link, but this link and list are within php code. I know I did something wrong, php code inside html, and html inside php.

```
<?php
foreach ($rows as $query_row) {
    $member_id=$query_row['user_id'];

    echo"<ul class='display_box' id='display_box'>";

    echo "<li><a href='<?php echo bp_core_get_user_domain( $member_id ); ?>'>
   <?php echo bp_core_fetch_avatar ( array( 'item_id' => $member_id, 'type' => 'thumb' ) ); ?> 
 <?php echo bp_core_get_user_displayname( $member_id ); ?>
           </a></li>";

                  echo"</ul>";



}//foreach
?>
```

Comment: You're already inside PHP and echo, so why use the PHP tag and echo? Just remove those.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
 echo "<li><a href='<?php echo bp_core_get_user_domain( $member_id ); ?>'>......
```

To:

```
 echo "<li><a href='" . bp_core_get_user_domain( $member_id ) . "'>" .
bp_core_fetch_avatar ( array( 'item_id' => $member_id, 'type' => 'thumb' ) ) .  
bp_core_get_user_displayname( $member_id ) . "</a></li>";
     echo"</ul>";
```

For example.

Answer (score 2):

You're already *in* PHP code.  When you're trying to do this:

```
echo "Some text <?php echo $someValue; ?> more text";
```

What you meant is this:

```
echo "Some text " . $someValue . " more text";
```

or perhaps this:

```
echo "Some text $someValue more text";
```

(if it's just a variable that can be auto-interpreted)

If you echo code, you're doing just that... echoing it.  If you want to *execute* code, don't put it in a string.  Just execute it.